# How to host nodejS+postgres application on digital-ocean?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I have followed traversy media tutorial to deploy nodejs app on digital-ocean. I am using postgres database of digital ocean. However on running `node app.js` command I am getting error

I have tried to follow many answers on stackoverflow but they have not solved the problem

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const db = require('./queries') // contains all query functions
const port = 3000

const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json()) 
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
)
app.use(cors())

app.get('/runs', db.getPlayers)

app.post('/year', db.getByYear)

//Handle production


    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public/'))

    //Handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (request, response) => response.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html') );


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

Error which I am getting is:-

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/vineet/IPL-Stats-Analysis-Dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vineet/IPL-Stats-Analysis-Dashboard/app.js:63:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

Comment: I think madflow is probably right, but my question to you Vineet, did you test this app at all? Always test your app along the way especially with tutorials that just rush you through app creation without a thorough walkthrough of what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with said tutorial - but the error denotes that another process (probably the same express app) is already listening on port 3000.

On Linux you can list all running process with the command `ps aux`. Look for another `node` process. If there is none - you can find which processes are listening on which ports by running `lsof -Pnl +M -i4` for ipv4 addresses and `lsof -Pnl +M -i6` for ipv6.

Or simply do `curl http://localhost:3000` in the Digitalocean droplet.

Answer (score 0):

If were your OS is Linux, just type on your terminal which is `killall -9 node`